Region between two spheres in spherical coordinates
Given the spheres
$$s_1\colon x^2+y^2+z^2=-2z\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2=1$$
and
$$s_2\colon x^2+y^2+z^2=-z\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2+\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}$$
I know they are below the $z=0$ plane and because of this
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\psi\leq\pi$$
Also, it's clear for me that
$$0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$$
However, my question is about $\rho$.In the plane $y=0$, I have the circles
$$x^2+z^2=-2z,\qquad x^2+z^2=-z$$
Hence, for the first one:
$$\rho^2\sin^2\psi\cos^2\theta^2+\rho^2\cos^2\psi+2\rho\cos\psi=0$$
which makes me think I'm not in the right way.
Should I use
$$y=\rho\cos\psi,\qquad z=\rho\sin\psi\sin\theta$$
instead? If so, may I affirm that
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\psi\leq\pi, \qquad0\leq\theta\leq2\pi,\qquad -\sin\theta\leq\rho\leq-2\sin\theta?$$

Are you trying to set up an integral?

Yes, trying to.

Using regular spherical coordinates centered on the $z$ axis will work better. The planar angular bounds are a lot more difficult to contend with than the $\psi$ angle. If you convert those two equations like you did but to regular spherical coordinates, you will find a much easier relationship.

But how am I suppose to find $\rho$ in this case?

You have to think about what finding a trace means geometrically. You are not "setting" a variable to $0$ like a light switch, you are finding the intersection between your surface and the surface $y=0$, a plane. You can't intersect a surface in one coordinate system and expect to move to a different coordinate afterwards, it's the same mistake as computing $f'(0) \neq (f(0))'$ in that wrong order. $y=0$ is the Cartesian equation for that surface, what would be the spherical equation to represent that plane entirely with spherical coordinates?

Sorry, but I still didn't get it. I mean, for me it's clear the way I did (using the regular spherical coordinates) to find the range of $\rho$, but it's kind impossible to solve the equation I found.

@NinadMunshi do you any books, materials to recommend? I do have to learn more about it.

What exactly do you mean by "region between two spheres"? Do you mean their intersection? Also, it would be helpful if you write down explicitely what your question is.

HINTS:

Leave alone rotation about z-axis. Can proceed only with graph of y-z sections from circle equation?
$$ \rho \cos \phi = 1,~\rho \cos \phi = 1/4.~$$

So, $1/4\cos\phi\leq\rho\leq1/\cos\phi$?
